# In which order should I edit a photo between Lightroom and Photoshop?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, photo-editing, workflow

Quick question: I currently use Lightroom and have Photoshop installed. If I intend to make an edit to a photo in Photoshop should I make my raw adjustments in Lightroom first then perform my Photoshop edits last, or the other way round?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would normally do the raw development work first in Lightroom or Camera Raw and then do the remainder of the work in Photoshop. Lightroom and ACR represent kind of the darkroom initial development stage of the image (white balance, exposure correction, etc) and Photoshop represents the cleanup or manipulation stage (depending on your needs) after the development. Your edits in Photoshop will probably result in either TIFF, PSD, or JPG files and ***not*** edits to the original raw file or sidecar file as Lightroom would do.